# Rebuilding a single corrupt table with dual master replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I have a replication setup with two MariaDB 10.2 instances set up in a dual-master configuration. On host A, a table has been corrupted somehow; whenever I try to read from it (including `CHECK TABLE tablename`) the process crashes.

```
May 05 13:04:05 hostA.my.internal mysqld[2666]: 2021-05-05 13:04:05 0x7f8b781c1700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in file /home/buildbot/buildbot/padding_for_CPACK_RPM_BUILD_SOURCE_DIRS_PREFIX/mariadb-10.2.36/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 376
May 05 13:04:05 hostA.my.internal mysqld[2666]: InnoDB: Failing assertion: btr_page_get_next(get_block->frame) == page_get_page_no(page)
```

I'm planning to take host A offline, and use `innochecksum` to diagnose the problem.

If, as I suspect, I need to rebuild this table, what is the quickest and safest way to go about it? I know I could repopulate host A's entire database from a dump of host B and rebuild replication from scratch, but I am hoping to avoid the trouble if it's possible.

If I get a dump of the table from host B and try importing it on host A, then `DROP TABLE` and all those `INSERT` statements (about 1.6 million rows) will be replicated, causing a lot of traffic and interfering with live services accessing host B.

Tagging as MySQL as well, since this seems like it should be applicable to either.

Comment: Was the table built when `innodb_file_per_table` was 'ON'?

Comment: Yes, all tables have separate `.frm` and `.ibd` files in `/var/lib/mysql/dbname/`

Comment: This looks like the unresolved bug [MDEV-22397](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22397). If you are able to provide MariaDB developers with a [private copy](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/meta/mariadb-ftp-server/) of your ibd file that may help prevent this occuring this again in a later. For your recovery [pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html) can be used in dual-master scenarios. I'd be looking to ensure that the destination is a new table `DROP TABLE` (NOT replicated). be careful.

Comment: @danblack if you can expand your comment into an answer showing how to use `pt-table-sync` to recover a single table in a dual-master setup, it would be appreciated. From looking at the documentation, it seems like it just populates a given table with data; how does this avoid replication of these statements to the other host? I think I'd need to drop the table and recreate it, to resolve the indexing issues.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure host B is your active host in the dual master
2. Rest of instructions are on host A
3. As reading from A.tablename will probably crash it, try this with another tablename to be familiar with what its doing. `pt-table-sync --dry-run --print --execute --sync-to-master h=hostB,D=db,t=sometablename`
4. look closely at the above.
5. `SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1` (if not already)
6. `STOP SLAVE`
7. To have a new table idb file: `set session sql_log_bin=0; RENAME TABLE tablename TO tablename_orig`
8. quick populate table from B without replicating: `( echo 'set session sql_log_bin=0;' ; mysqldump --single-transaction --host hostB db tablename ) | mysql --host A db`
9. `start slave`
10. `pt-table-sync --print --execute --sync-to-master h=hostB,D=db,t=tablename`

Please read [pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html) carefully. Its been a few years since I've used this. Note the bits about it locking tables briefly on the master for small periods of time to read data in small chunks. This, and all the other interactions should be obvious on from the `--dry-run --print`.

Comment: After success, please help pay back a free database and assistance with a [bug report contribution](https://jira.mariadb.org) of a full error log, the history of table changes and if multiple database versions have been run on this table, those versions. A private upload of ibd file may also help if you are allowed.

Comment: A couple of pain points here: You need to have identical users on both servers, with access allowed from remote IPs, before `pt-table-sync` would work. The `dry-run` just shows [a bunch of zeroes](https://imgur.com/a/ZrHumNz), which is not terribly helpful. The old table had to be dropped completely before using the output from `mysqldump` (identifiers such as index names must be unique.) The `--print` option prints every SQL statement, so best to redirect output into a file. Even after all that, still dealing with replication errors like `handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND` etc.

Comment: And this, from the documentation. "Sync master2 in a master-master replication configuration, ***where master2’s copy of db.tbl is known or suspected to be incorrect***: `pt-table-sync --execute --sync-to-master h=master2,D=db,t=tbl`" So your instructions have the wrong host in the DSN. But that's on me for not reading the manual closely enough.